# I want to only show the rows that isActive is True with AG Grid

Tags: ag-grid-react

I'm using NextJS, ReactJS, and AG Grid. I'm accessing a database from my backend and making a call to the front end to get the data. At the same time I'm setting the row data for AG Grid. I want to only show the data where isActive is set to True. So I can "delete" by changing a row's isActive to false instead of deleting the item from the database. So all in all I want to only show the data that has isActive set to True.

This is my code now:

const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([]);

```
const [colDefs, setColDefs] = useState([
    {headerName: '', checkboxSelection: true},
    {field: 'id', headerName:'ID', sortable: true, filter: true},
    {field: 'course', headerName:'Golf Course', sortable: true, filter: true},
    {field: 'city', headerName:'City', sortable: true, filter: true},
    {field: 'state', headerName:'State', sortable: true, filter: true},
    {field: 'isActive', headerName:'Is Active', }
]);

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/getgolfcourses')
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(rowData => setRowData(rowData))
}, [])
```

I was thinking of doing something inside of this useEffect but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Before passing data to the grid(via setRowData), you can apply the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function on your data set, and then pass it to the grid. when you update any row's **isActive**  property, refresh the grid. Filter the data set first and then pass it to the grid. Hope this will help.